# Webkit.net scroll document programmatically

Tags: .net, webkit, scroll, webkit.net

if I use [Webkit.Net](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/) to display HTML in my winforms application everytime I set the `DocumentText` property, the document is scrolled back to the beginning.

How can I get the current scroll position and set it after I changed the document text?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that I've overlooked the `ScrollOffset` property :).

I'd like to add that it is not sufficient to set it directly after updating the `DocumentText` property since webkit loads the document asyncronously. Therefore I have to intercept the `DocumentCompleted` event like:

```
Point p;

void UpdateDocument() {
  p=webkitBrowser.ScrollOffset;
  webkitBrowser.DocumentText = CreateNewDocument();
}

private void webKitBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
  webkitBrowser.ScrollOffset = p;
}
```

This works as I needed.

Thanks anyway.